# torch DDP Multi-GPU gives low accuracy metric

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, multi-gpu

I am trying Multi-GPU, single machine DDP training in PyTorch (CIFAR-10 + ResNet-18 setup). You can refer to the model architecture code [here](https://github.com/arjun-majumdar/CNN_Classifications/blob/master/ResNet18_swish_torch.py) and the full training code [here](https://github.com/arjun-majumdar/CNN_Classifications/blob/master/multigpu_singlemachine_ddp_torch.py).

Within main() function, the training loop is:

```
for epoch in range(1, num_epochs + 1):
        # Initialize metric for metric computation, for each epoch-
        running_loss = 0.0
        running_corrects = 0.0
    
        model.train()

        # Inform DistributedSampler about current epoch-
        train_loader.sampler.set_epoch(epoch)

        # One epoch of training-
        for batch_idx, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
            images = images.to(rank)
            labels = labels.to(rank)

            # Get model predictions-
            outputs = model(images)
              
            # Compute loss-
            J = loss(outputs, labels)
                
            # Empty accumulated gradients-
            optimizer.zero_grad()
                
            # Perform backprop-
            J.backward()
                
            # Update parameters-
            optimizer.step()

            '''                
            global step
            optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'] = custom_lr_scheduler.get_lr(step)
            step += 1
            ''' 
            
            # Compute model's performance statistics-
            running_loss += J.item() * images.size(0)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            running_corrects += torch.sum(predicted == labels.data)
            
        train_loss = running_loss / len(train_dataset)
        train_acc = (running_corrects.double() / len(train_dataset)) * 100
        print(f"GPU: {rank}, epoch = {epoch}; train loss = {train_loss:.4f} & train accuracy = {train_acc:.2f}%")
```

The problem is that the train accuracy being computed in this way is very low (say only 7.44% on average) across 8 GPUs. But, when I obtain the saved model and test its accuracy with the following code:

```
def test_model_progress(model, test_loader, test_dataset):
    total = 0.0
    correct = 0.0
    running_loss_val = 0.0

    with torch.no_grad():
        with tqdm(test_loader, unit = 'batch') as tepoch:
            for images, labels in tepoch:
                tepoch.set_description(f"Validation: ")
                
                images = images.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)
                
                # Set model to evaluation mode-
                model.eval()
            
                # Predict using trained model-
                outputs = model(images)
                _, y_pred = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                
                # Compute validation loss-
                J_val = loss(outputs, labels)
                
                running_loss_val += J_val.item() * labels.size(0)
    
                # Total number of labels-
                total += labels.size(0)

                # Total number of correct predictions-
                correct += (y_pred == labels).sum()
                
                tepoch.set_postfix(
                    val_loss = running_loss_val / len(test_dataset),
                    val_acc = 100 * (correct.cpu().numpy() / total)
                )
            
        
    # return (running_loss_val, correct, total)
    val_loss = running_loss_val / len(test_dataset)
    val_acc = (correct / total) * 100

    return val_loss, val_acc.cpu().numpy()

test_loss, test_acc = test_model_progress(trained_model, test_loader, test_dataset)

print(f"ResNet-18 (multi-gpu DDP) test metrics; loss = {test_loss:.4f} & acc = {test_acc:.2f}%")
# ResNet-18 (multi-gpu DDP) test metrics; loss = 1.1924 & acc = 59.88%
```

Why is there this discrepancy? What am I missing?

Comment: Please be aware that there is also a dedicated data science stackexchange site.

Comment: @Sebastian I don't think that this would be a good fit for Data Science, but rather AI stackoverflow?

Comment: Does it work if you train with only one GPU? How to do get the acc across all GPU? Did you syncronize/gather the metrics? Did you use synchronized batch normalization?

Comment: @MCiel; Yes it works for a single GPU. No, I didn't sync/gather the metrics. **Do you have any example to demo this?** Yes, I use sync BN

Comment: You may use all_gather to synchronize the predictions (see https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/blob/482f60fe55c364e50e4fc4b50893a25d8cc261b0/mmdet/apis/test.py#L160, note that this does not only use all_gather but tells you how to gather non-tensor objects or objects with varied length) or simply use pytorch-lightning's logger which offers options in the interface to automatically gather for you (here: https://github.com/CielAl/SimCLR-Lightning/blob/main/simclr_lightning/models/lightning_modules/simclr_wrapper.py#L155).